# Webform token in emails: need example

Tags: 7, webforms, tokens

I've got multiple web forms that email their submissions. I need to break it out into fields and keep it clean.

Say, on my webform, I've got a field named zip_code. How can I print that in a token, with no label?

Thank you.

EDIT: I want to use the built-it (but not documented) functionality

Answer (score 3):

Under Webforms > E-mails > E-mail template choose Custom Template.

Remove the [submission:values] token. That's what lists all the fields and their values with labels. Customize the other text as you wish.

Note the "Browse available tokens." link below the text box. This pops up a window that shows you what placeholders you can put in to build your email. You can even click on the browse tokens popup to add them to the text field. Some of them can be used as-is. Some need additional info, like the field tokens.

Field values are under the Submission header.

For your zip_code field example, you can use:

For just field:
[submission:values:zip_code]

For just label:
[submission:values:zip_code:label]

For label and field:
[submission:values:zip_code:withlabel]

You'll see there's lots of other stuff you can use, too.

Hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to find out how to remove the empty fields from Webforms emails. I ended up creating the template (webform-mail.tpl.php) in the theme and using some PHP. Maybe this will help get you started. I'll share it here. You can also look at the original file in the module for some more info on the variables available to you. If you dump the values of those variables you'll learn a lot. That's how I got started.

Now I was asked to print the labels (in caps!) but you can take those lines out.

This code also respects the excluded field settings in the UI, so that going forward, the users can control what fields they see or don't see. I'm new to PHP and Drupal so this may not be the best way to do it, but it worked for me.

```
<?php
function email_print($text) {
  global $email;
  print ($email['html'] ? '<p>' : '') . t($text) . ($email['html'] ? "</p>\n" : "\n");
}
?>

<?php email_print('On [current-date:short] a request was submitted by [submission:user] from form [node:title]') ?>
<?php email_print('-----------------------------------------------------'); ?>

<?php

// Make sure we have a submission; avoids error in the admin UI where this file is parsed for display
if ($submission) {
  // Get excluded fields
  $excluded = array_values($email['excluded_components']);

  foreach($submission->data as $key => $field) {
    // Reset include boolean
    $include = true;

    // Get value
    $value = trim($field[0]);
    // If it's blank, don't include it
    if (strlen($value) == 0) {
      $include = false;
    }

    // If it's listed as excluded, don't include it.
    if (in_array ($key, $excluded)) {
      $include = false;
    }

    // If it should be included...
    if ($include) {
      // ...get and upcase the label...
      $label = strtoupper(trim($node->webform['components'][$key]['name']));
      // ...and print out the field.
      email_print($label);
      email_print($value);
      print "\n"; // Blank line between
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I'm not much of a programmer; I'm actually just looking for how to use the built-in (but not documented) functionality.